# How to get the number in table and add it in other

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc

I have one table for facture with NumFacture, price and price with taxes.

Now I want to get the numFacture from this table and add this number for each product in this facture for add it in my detailFacture table

I tried the following, but it didn't get me the numFacture and it always start with number 1

```
int numfacture;
//add facture in table facture

for (numfacture = 0; numfacture < listeclient.Count; numfacture++)
{
    this._context.InsertFacture(numfacture, client.Telephone, prixAvantTaxe, prixTaxe);                   
}

//add detailfacture
foreach (AchatLivreViewModel l in _panier.ListeElements)
{
    this._context.InsertDetailsFacture(numfacture, l.Isbn, l.Prix);
    numfacture++;
}
```

An example of what I want:
If I have 3 products in my cart with `numFacture = 8`
i would like have something like this in my detailsfacture table:

> for the first product in my cart: `numfacture = 8,  price = 20$`
>
> for the second product in my cart: `numfacture = 8,  price = 50$`
>
> for the third product in my cart: `numfacture = 8  price = 30$`

Comment: I would suggest you don't want to store the subtotal in your table. Just calculate it when you need it. You already have the quantity and the price. Simply multiply those in the subtotal property and don't store the computed value.

Comment: my teacher want that so..

Comment: Well then add the property to the model. Then you would pass in the expression. And make sure that when you update either of those columns that you also update the computed column....another reason why this is not a good idea.

Comment: yes its complicate... i really dont know how to do that

Comment: It would be just like any other property. Add a new called ExtendedPrice or whatever. Then when you pass "numfacture * price" to the Insert method.

Comment: oh ok i think a understand... i should add numFacture in my model? but what model because actually i dont have model for facture...

Comment: I couldn't possibly know as I know nothing of your project other than 5-6 lines of code you posted. Add it this._context.InsertDetailsFacture would be my guess.